# perl PDL module fails to install on linux

Tags: perl

I am using `cpan -L local PDL::Graphics::PLplot`.  I am getting a failure message.

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/plplot.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
Non-zero exit status: 2
Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/plplot_library_tests.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
Non-zero exit status: 2
Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=3, Tests=0,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.20 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.24 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/3 test programs. 0/0 subtests failed.
Makefile:803: recipe for target 'test_dynamic' failed
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 2
-> FAIL Installing PDL::Graphics::PLplot
```

Comment: There is a very good chance that this module is available from repository of the Linux distribution. Investigate if it is can be installed through package installation manager.

Comment: Have you installed `libplplot.so` ? It installed fine here (Ubuntu 20.04, perl version 5.30) after running `sudo apt-get install libplplot-dev`

Comment: Yes at some point doing my research i installed `libplplot-dev `

Comment: @user3525290 What version of perl are you using? Which OS?

Comment: I am using perl 5.26

Answer (score 1):

When installing using cpanm I noticed I was missing some modules `libpdl-stats-perl Cannot find hdf library, libdf.a, libplplotd.so, HDF, GD, Proj` once those were installed it started working.  I did have to install to a non standard perl directory.